# Java/Swing GUI programming with NetBeans 6.X framework

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans6.1

I am using NetBeans 6.1.

When I am trying to create a "Java Desktop Application"-project, a skeleton application is created with lots of [WTF](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wtf) code.

How can I understand those code?

Can anyone suggest me any web-link?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285377/creating-guis-using-java-swing-with-netbeans-ide) SO question, some links are provided. But they are not answering to my problem.

Suppose, what is a `SingleFrameApplication`-class? What is a `FrameView`-class?Upon what philosophy the application is divided into "`MyFormApp.java`" and "`MyFormView.java`" files? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it "WTF code"? Just because you don't understand it?

Did you notice the description at the bottom of the project wizard screen when you create a new Java Desktop Application? It gives you some hints to what you're creating:

> Creates a skeleton of a desktop application based on the **Swing Application Framework (JSR 296)**. This template provides basic application infrastructure such as a menu bar, persisting of window state, and status bar. With this template, you can also generate code to create a GUI interface for a database table.

See [Swing Application Framework](https://appframework.dev.java.net/).

By the way, NetBeans 6.1 is old. The current version is 6.9.1.

Comment: Can you suggest any book for this?

Comment: I don't think there are any books on the Swing Application Framework; there is a JSR for it (so it's a proposed standard) but it's not a completely ready and fully developed framework, as far as I know. The web page that I linked to contains documentation.